# Does constructive interference automatically imply bright fringes at all times?

Tags: optics, waves, electric-fields, interference, diffraction

Suppose two waves interfere constructively at some point, in a double slit experiment set-up. This essentially means that the two waves have their peaks and troughs in sync with each other, and there is a phase difference of $2n\pi$. However, it is said that, we obtain bright fringes where waves interfere constructively.

However,  this seems to be somewhat of an approximation to me. At constructive interference, if a wave has a peak at some point on the screen, the other wave would also have a peak. Similarly, if one wave has a trough, then the other wave also has a trough. However, how can we be sure that the first wave would definitely have a peak or a trough at that point ? Why not any other point in between ?

As the wave is moving forward, we can think of the screen as some point $x_0$ along the direction in which the wave moves. As the wave moves forward, the point $x_0$ on the wave, can be the peak, trough or any other point depending on time. So, the amplitude at any point on the screen oscillates too.

Since the displacement of the field at the screen oscillate, shouldn't we get an oscillating or 'flickering' intensity fringe pattern, instead of a constant bright-dark pattern ? Shouldn't the bright regions flicker extremely fast ?

Will this be true, even in case of double slit diffraction ?

Comment: *constructive interference* -> maximum amplitude

Comment: @Farcher yes, but isn't the instantaneous amplitude changing periodically, at places where the waves don't interfere destructively ? So, shouldn't the instantaneous intensity on the screen change periodically, even for bright fringes ?

Comment: Amplitude is the maximum displacement from an “equilibrium” position but the value changes with time between zero and the amplitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detector, such as your eye, does not respond at the rate of oscillation of the optical or RF frequency, instead it responds to the variation of its peaks or to variation of its average power (energy per cycle). These variations are many orders of magnitude slower than the oscillation rate. For example your eyes can tell the difference of brightness but only at the rate of few hundred hertz. In an *ideal* double-slit experiment the nulls are completely zero non-oscillating in intensity, there really is no energy; at the intensity peaks those do fluctuate at the rate of the oscillation (optical or RF) frequency but the detector ignores that and responds to the peaks or rms energy.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a stone dropped in a pool, the waves will be present forever if the water is ideal and the pool walls perfectly reflecting. If by some coincidence in maybe a 1000 years the surface looks calm, the energy is not lost .... waves will reemerge again.

For light an excited electron creates a photon in the EM field, its energy would stay in the field forever if we could trap it in perfectly reflecting mirrors.

But these are ideal experiments, in reality all water waves typically crash of the beach and lose their energy.  Every photon is created by an electron/atom and and every photon will eventually be absorbed by an electron atom, this process best described by probability (or Quantum Mechanics).

For water we can see the waves but for light we never see them, we can only absorb the photons in our eyes.

If 2 photons arrive exactly in phase at our eye, the eye atom will absorb one and the other will pass/scatter to be absorbed elsewhere.  If 2 photons arrive out of phase, there is a higher probability of non-absorption ... but with the interaction the photons will be scattered/separated and then get absorbed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Constructive interference also creates dark fringes where trough meets trough.